# How to enable developer mode on iOS device withoout starting Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, instruments

I want to test an app on a iOS device but, when I try to do it, I get the following error: "Failed to start Instruments daemon on 'iOS_Device_Name (X.X.X)' (The service is invalid.)"

I've checked that "Developer" option in Settings app doesn't appears until I open Xcode and when I do this, this error disappears. However, I connect to the Mac via SSH, so I can't open Xcode.

How can I solve this problem without starting Xcode, via SSH?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that like that.

But what you can do is to export your app to test as AdHoc with an AdHoc certificat and then install them on your test device without opening Xcode.